# Create one to many relation in Excel Filter

Tags: excel, filter, one-to-many

I am creating dependency list for our products. For example;

```
*Product 1* uses A.dll, B.dll, C.dll
*Product 2* uses A.dll, D.dll
*Product 3* uses B.dll, C.dll
```

well, when user Product 2 from the combobox (filter) in excel, only A and B dll names must be shown on the dependency column.

I dont want to add like

```
Product 1    A.dll
Product 1    B.dll
Product 1    C.dll
Product 2    A.dll
Product 2    D.dll
Product 3    B.dll
Product 3    C.dll
```

I think that it should be done in Advanced Filter, but i tried to do that it didnt work to me. I choose the range for Product 2, but it only shows me one dependend dll name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it is not 100% clear what you want... with a simple helper-column it should be doable...

The formula I used(D2 and then copied down):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(J:L,MATCH($G$1,I:I,0),),C2)>0
```

[image]

And now simply filter it by the helper column only showing `TRUE`